# How to load all pdf files from warehouse to my existing android application

Tags: android, android-listview, pdf-generation

I wants to show my `pdf` files uploaded on live url to my existing android application.

I have used below code.

```
File file = new File("https://admin.ipublishcentral.com/assetmaster/asset/295087");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file); 
Intent printIntent = new Intent(All_Books_Activity.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);  printIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); 
printIntent.putExtra("title", "DEMO PDF");
startActivity(printIntent);
```

But results are confusing.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/admin.ipublishcentral.com/assetmaster/asset/viewasset/asset/295087: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you should not do like this. You have to download the pdf file to local then user that location

Comment: if user gets all files on his device so can you imagine how much storage required on device. i don't think that is suitable to my question.

Comment: U may delete the file once u have done.

Comment: but i don't want to download full book for users. i just want to show only 5 pages from any pdf. so downloading should not be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("https://admin.ipublishcentral.com/assetmaster/asset/295087");
```

Use file URI only when loading the local pdf file not for remote pdf through http link.

You can directly pass the HTTP link to Uri constructor to build the direct HTTP link URI.

```
Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
    printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://admin.ipublishcentral.com/assetmaster/asset/295087"), "application/pdf");
    printIntent.putExtra("title", "Demo PDF");
    startActivity(printIntent);
```